# Magento Random Error SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' (4)

Tags: magento, mysql-error-2003

I have a magento application on a dedicated server and connect to another remote dedicated server where only mysql server is running.

The application is running fine. But i receive random emails [ As i set magento to send error reports to my email ] with the error `[SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on]`.

I not only get this error but also the error below

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2013] Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading authorization packet', system error: 0
```

As the appliaction is running, i cannot understand what is going on and how to approach to this issue.

Plz suggest. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow your connection between the webserver (running Magento) and your MySQL server is instable. To test if that is the problem you might want to try to install MySQL on the same server the Magento is running on, and test for a while if the problems are gone.
If indeed the connection is instable, it might be a problem in the nework between the two servers, or maybe they are not both configured to use full duplex on the network.